# Collections.max function for Iterable<Integer> in Java

Tags: java, collections, max, standard-library

The Java [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) method takes only a collection of a sortable ([`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) object. However since the collection is not necessarily sorted, I don't see any reason not to implement the same max function for [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) types.

Is there a max method for `Iterable<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` in Java's standard library?

Comment: Where does it says that Collections.max only takes a sorted collection?  From the docs it looks like it will take anything that implements Collection.

Comment: @Outlaw Programmer: that's what he said. "...since the collection is not necessarily sorted..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collections.max` was introduced in 1.2. `Iterable` was introduced in 1.5.

It's rare to have an `Iterable` that is not a `Collection`. If you do then it's straightforward to implement (be careful to read the spec). If you think it is really important you can submit an RFE in the [Java Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/) (or vote if there is already one there).

Comment: Implementing an Iterable is implementing two functions, implementing a collection is more than double the work. So if I want to make a quick iterable of a class I created it's much easier.

Comment: Collections.max(new ArrayList<X>(0) { @Override public Iterator<X> iterator() { return iterable.iterator(); }})

;)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: You are a bad man. Never violate the contract of an interface. For instance, an implementation of Collections.max could legitimately start by calling Collection#isEmpty() and throwing an error if it returns true.

Comment: @chrispy Yes(ish). May have helped if I added some comment in my comment. Calling `toArray` often has better properties than calling `iterator` (works with concurrent/synchronised implementations, and may well be faster). / I note the many of the classes within collections don't implemented the interfaces correctly, and the collection interfaces are really ropey (check out the missing throws documentation in the new (at time of writing) Java SE 8 stuff).

Answer (score 16):

While Guava is not Java's standard library, it's close enough...

[`E com.google.common.collect.Ordering#max(Iterable<E> iterable)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#max%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

e.g. `T max = Ordering.natural().max(myIterable);`

As to why the standard library does not implement it, it may be because [a Collection must be finite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size()), but [an Iterable need not be](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#cycle%28T...%29)—and, arguably, one should *never* accept an Iterable if a non-terminating Iterable would cause your code to loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm… no, there isn’t. If you want to use [Collections.max()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) you have to convert your [Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) into a [Collection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) first, probably by adding all of the elements into a [List](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (or [Set](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), depending on the data).

Answer (score 0):

My observation of `Iterable` is that, while it could be used in preference to `Collection` in many places where a stream of data is needed but not the various collection methods like size, it typically isn't within the Java core libraries.

This is just an inference on my part, but it feels like the Java designers are really sticking to `Iterable` just being a way to use the enhanced `for` statement for a given stream of data, and use `Collection` where a bunch of data items are needed, even if `Iterable` would be sufficient.

A look at the Javadocs for [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) adds weight to this viewpoint, as this is the only thing called out in the class-level Javadocs:

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the enhanced `for` statement (sometimes called the "for-each loop" statement).

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of streams with Java 8, operations like this that could be done on an `Iterable` are generally instead done on a `Stream`.

[`StreamSupport.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream(java.util.Spliterator,boolean)) can convert any `Iterable` to a `Stream`, which means that the stream-based approach to finding a max value can be used for an arbitrary `Iterable`:

```java
Optional<Integer> max = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Answer (score -2):

By definition the elements of the collection must be "sortable" (specifically, they must implements `Comparable`) since in order to compute the maximum, it must be possible to work out whether one element is greater than another (which is exactly what Comparable means).

The [max() method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) in the Collections class has essentially the exact type signature you posted there, so it should suit your purpose.

Comment: I want to compute the max of an Iterable which is not a Collection